# Display audio metadata while streaming music over A2DP?

Tags: bluetooth, music, a2dp

I've paired my mobile phone with my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop via Bluetooth and can stream audio from the phone to the desktop using A2DP.

Every time I would like to know which song is playing, I have to glance at my phone. Since most car stereos are capable of displaying track information for music streamed via A2DP, I assume there is a similar method for getting this information to my desktop.

My searching failed to turn anything useful up. Is it possible to display a notification (via libnotify or something similar) when the current song changes? The app I'm streaming the music from is Google Music on Android, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata is sent over AVRCP profile, not over A2DP. If your phone does AVRCP 1.0 then it will not send any metadata info. If it does AVRCP 1.3 or above then you should see metadata. Google play music player does not support sending track number and controlling repeat and random.

Comment: Interestingly, the Bluetooth adapter I have came with a utility for Windows that displays this information in a little popup window that sits next to the taskbar.